# Make typescript to output "require" instead of "import"

Tags: node.js, typescript, import, require, es6-modules

I am transpiling typescript into javascript for an application targetting Node v.14. I want my output to have `require` instead of `import` statements. My config file looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./build",
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I get import statements instead. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the [`module`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) to `commonjs`. If you do this, you also don't need to specify `"moduleResolution": "node"` as `node` is the default for when `module` is `commonjs`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  // ...
}
```