# Compile Typescript so that it does not use require() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Writing a PacMan game in TypeScript, my `app.ts` file has in import for the PacMan class like this:

```js
import { PacMan } from "./pacman"
```

Using TypeScript 4.9.4 and for some reason unknown to me, I needed to configure NodeJS 18.12.1, this gets compiled in WebStorm 2022.3 to a line

```js
var pacman_1 = require("./pacman");
```

For that line, my browser (Firefox 108.0) throws an exception

> ReferenceError: require is not defined

[I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35706164/typescript-import-as-vs-import-require) [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39658232/import-vs-require-in-typescript) [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67899996/typescript-import-require-vs-import-from) [stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66383475/make-typescript-to-output-require-instead-of-import) but honestly, I hardly understand anything.

I tried suggestions for changes in `tsconfig.json`, so I set `"target": "es5",` and `"esModuleInterop": true,` but that didn't result in any better in the browser. My full config is currently

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I think the problem lies in the choice of the [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html). I don't know what CommonJS or RequireJS or an AMD is, nor how I would configure that correctly. I don't know the difference between ES5 and ES6, so it's guesswork for me, or "trial and error".

I thought TypeScript would compile to JavaScript. Can I configure "module" to [VanillaJS](http://vanilla-js.com/) maybe? Or do I really have to go with a dependency like RequireJS? If so, why doesn't the TypeScript compiler compile that dependency into the resulting JavaScript?

Comment: The native JavaScript module system is ES6. Alternatively, you can bundle your code. CommonJS is a module system specific to Node.js. There wasn't any VanillaJs module system before ES6.

Comment: @jabaa: oh, you mean I should put "es6" into "module", not "target"? Holy cow ...

Comment: `target` and `module` should be set to ES6.

Comment: sh§$%&, yes, that works. I get some other errors now, but that's ok. I can look into those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't believe that it so simple and [not documented in `module`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html). Thanks to [@jabaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16540390/jabaa), I simply used `"module": "es6"` in my `tsconfig.json` and that fixed it.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es6",
    "target": "es6",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: The section in your link describes TypeScript modules. You have to read the section about the transpiler configuration: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module